# Dashtype line in svg path

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

i want to create dash type line in  svg using path. how can i apply dash style to svg path to make a dashed line. Please refer below SVG.

```
<path id="container_svg_John_0" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="url(#container_svg_John0Gradient)" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 0 -17.25 L 21.633333333333333 -112.12499999999999 M 21.633333333333333 -112.12499999999999 L 43.266666666666666 -51.75 M 43.266666666666666 -51.75 L 86.53333333333333 -25.875 M 86.53333333333333 -25.875 L 108.16666666666666 -155.25 "></path>
```

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `stroke-dasharray` property:

```
<path 
  id="container_svg_John_0" 
  fill="none" 
  stroke-width="3" 
  stroke="url(#container_svg_John0Gradient)" 
  stroke-linecap="butt" 
  stroke-linejoin="round" 
  stroke-dasharray="10,10"
  d="M 0 -17.25 L 21.633333333333333 -112.12499999999999 M 21.633333333333333 -112.12499999999999 L 43.266666666666666 -51.75 M 43.266666666666666 -51.75 L 86.53333333333333 -25.875 M 86.53333333333333 -25.875 L 108.16666666666666 -155.25 "></path>
```

It takes a comma separated value that represents solid,void.  Interesting side note: If you have an odd number of values in the array, when it goes to repeat, the pattern is reversed, i.e the first value is now a void, second is a solid.

`stroke-dasharray="10,5,10"` is the same as  `stroke-dasharray="10,5,10,10,5,10"`